# Displaying Fields in a Drill Through Table Dynamically

Tags: powerbi, dax, linechart, measure, drillthrough

I want to be able to dynamically apply a "is less than or equal to" filter to my drill through table. Currently, I have a line chart, that has a % on the y-axis, con_seasoning on x-axis and Date as the legend. On my Drill through table, I have Date and con_seasoning as the filters. However, the line chart shows cumulative count, so it is possible an end user can drill through on a date/con_seasoning combo with no values for that selected combination. But my end goal is to be able to show all the contracts that have less than or equal to of the con_seasoning selected by the date. Currently, I am able to achieve this by manually adjusting the con_seasoning drill through filter to "less than or equal to", but this is not feasible for an end user. I've attempted to build a Dynamic Selection measure to no avail. Below is what I'm doing manually, but would like done dynamically. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]